# How to make rsync create constant ACLs under cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, rsync, cacls

I used a cygwin command like

```
rsync -rtl --delete --delete-excluded /cygwin/c /mydisk
```

on Windows XP and ended up with a **94 line long completely insane ACL** for `/mydisk/c`. None of the options `rtl` should preserve ACL and there's surely no option for creating such a big mess.

I want no access control on `/mydisk` (i.e. an ACL granting access to everyone). I think I can fix it now using

```
cd /mydisk; cacls . /t /p everyone:f
```

*Is this correct?*

*How can I make rsync do it this way?*

Comment: I would like to know a way to have `rsync` not touch my ACLs as well (i.e. just leave the ACL handling to Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync support keeping permissions with `--perms` and changing permissions with `--chmod`. There is also something called `--acls`, but I'm not sure how this is applied under cygwin.